# Read Next.js errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, next.js

Every time I have an error on next.js, I'm wondering how to locate the error in my code.

If it was 'regular' React or JS code, it would show exactly where's the error in my code, but since Next.js renders the code on the server, the errors boundary is strange and I cant understand exactly where is my error (it is React error, but shown as Next.js error)
Is there any smart way of locate errors on Next.js?

[image]

Comment: In apis, you can set error handler middleware using amazing `next-connect` library [https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-connect]